# Get most recent/newest image from ECR using terraform data source

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ecr

I have an ECR repository named `workflow` and in this repository, there is 5 image pushed using GitHub action.

Now I have a terraform workflow that will just use the image from ECR and using this ECR image builds the ECS container definition.

so now I want to fetch the latest image with the tag whatever it would be...

I tried the below thing

```
data "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  name = "workflow"
}
```

and then

```
 "image": "${data.aws_ecr_repository.example.repository_url}"
```

but here I only get the Url for the repo without a tag

so how can I pass here the latest or newest image with the tag?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (at this time) with Terraform unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkB ok or maybe somehow we can get all tags in terraform using a data source and then loop over this.

Comment: data "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  name = "workflow"
}
output "ecr_repo" {
  value = data.aws_ecr_repository.example.tags
}
i tried below output block but it prints out the 
"ecr_repo = tomap({})"
this thing how can i get data inside map like tags

Comment: You can't. Look at the documentation if you don't believe me.  The standard way of  handling this is to have your CI/CD process that builds and pushes the image to ECR pass the tag it created as an input variable into your terraform commands.

Comment: okay got it for doing this thing inside the terraform itself i used external data source and from there i write a bash script and there i fetched the latest image tag and pass and this works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like this feature is [now available](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/26857)

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "service_image" {
  repository_name = "my/service"
  most_recent       = true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same, look if this documentation suites you
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.34.0/docs/data-sources/ecr_image

it includes a way to obtain the image:

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "service_image" {
    repository_name = "my/service"
    image_tag       = "latest"
}
```

the problem of that is that "image_uri" isnt in the resource.
There is an open issue in Github about it:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/24526

Meanwhile you can use this format for the url:

```
"${var.aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${var.project_name}:${var.latest-Tag}"
```

Answer (score 2):

As terraform is not capable for this thing and you want to use still terraform in you are workplace then you can use `terraform as an external data source`

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "snipe-main" {
container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
[
  {
"image":"${data.aws_ecr_repository.example.repository_url}:${data.external.current_image.result["image_tag"]}"
   }
]
TASK_DEFINITION 
}

data "external" "current_image" {
  program = ["bash", "./ecs-task.sh"]
}
output "get_new_tag" {
  value = data.external.current_image.result["image_tag"]
}
cat ECS-task.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
imageTag=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name <<here your repo name>> --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]')
imageTag=`sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$imageTag"`
jq -n --arg imageTag "$imageTag" '{"image_tag":$imageTag}'

exit 0
```

Comment: Very smart solution @rohan-jangid.  I have been trying to get the latest image dynamically for a while and this just does that.  For those, that are getting an error "jq: command not found", you could just use an echo '{"image_tag":"'$imageTag'"}' since all we are doing is creating a json string.

Comment: @SonnyN thanks if it's helpful for you please mark it as accepted for other, users don't struggle to find a better answer

Comment: As an addition, the value the data resource returns is only read on creation of the data resource. Follow up `plan/apply` will return the same value, not a more recent value if available.